# Adding timestep to video frames in dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently working on a ConvLSTM Encoder-Decoder Network, and I've been trying to prepare a dataset for it. According to Tensorflow's documentation, the recommended input data format for ConvLSTM2D layers is:

`(samples, time, rows, cols, channels)`

The original dataset is a sequence of image frames, and I've been able to prepare the dataset in this format:

`(samples, rows, cols, channels)`

How can I add timestep info to the dataset? The frames themselves are in order, but I don't know how to add the timestep data to the dataset.

My current code that pulls the images into a numpy array is below:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import imageio

original_data = []

for img_path in sorted(glob.glob("../Datasets/Test_Dataset/*.png")):
    img = imageio.imread(img_path)
    original_data.append(img)    

original_data = np.array(original_data)
```

Comment: What do you mean by numberOfVideos and frames? In the above code only the samples (frames) are read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
original_data = original_data.reshape(numberOfVideos, frames, rows, cols, channels)
```

Comment: What do you mean by numberOfVideos and frames? In the above code only the samples (frames) are read?

Comment: `numberOfVideos` is how many videos they have in the dataset. And `frames` is how many frames each video has. This solution implies all videos have the same number of frames. I don't know the dataset, so this is a general answer. If you have only one video, you can use `numberOfVideos = 1`.

Comment: In case the `frames` are not the same , what are you doing?

Comment: If the videos have different number of frames, you can pad the videos to the same length, maybe use a `Masking` layer. You can also process videos individually, leaving the frame dimension variable (as `None`).

Comment: what do you mean  by process video individually? You mean to train each one alone?